# How to append data-provider name along with method name in Extent Report?

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am working on Extent Report framework in my current project. In my test class I am using Data-provider class to import the test data. The particular test contains 10 validation test iterating the data-provider key.
When it comes to Extent report I am writing the method name into the report
But I have to differentiate each data-provider test with a name matching to each validation test. 
Here are my script :1. Extent Report Config:

```
   @BeforeSuite
   public void setUp()
   {
       htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/extentReport.html");
       extent = new ExtentReports();
       extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

       extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows");
       extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "1016086");
       extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
       extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "BABURAJ V D");

       htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
       htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Extent report");
       htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Final Report");
   }


      @BeforeClass
      public synchronized void beforeClass() {
          test = extent.createTest(getClass().getSimpleName());
          parentTest.set(test);

      }

      @BeforeMethod
      public synchronized void beforeMethod(Method method) {

          child = parentTest.get().createNode(method.getName());
          childTest.set(child);

      }
      @AfterMethod
        public synchronized void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
                childTest.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
            else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
                childTest.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
            else
                childTest.get().pass("Test passed");

   }

   @AfterSuite

   public void tearDown(){

       extent.flush();
   }
```

[image: Extend Report]

```
@Test(priority = 2, dataProvider = GE_XR240_DEVICE_DataProvider.DEVICE_ADD_VALIDATIONS, dataProviderClass = GE_XR240_DEVICE_DataProvider.class)

public void OPTIMA_XR240_FAILED_MESSAGE_VALIDATION(Map<String, String> deviceTestData) throws InterruptedException { }
```

These are the validations happening in that particular test OPTIMA_XR240_FAILED_MESSAGE_VALIDATION or the error message which should be displayed in the UI:

```
Add Device Failed - System name should be filled
Add Device Failed - System Id should be filled
Add Device Failed - Manufacturer should be assigned
Add Device Failed - System model should be assigned
Add Device Failed - Current IP Address / Host Name should be filled
```

So that I have make the report which should contain a piece of information relates to the validation it performs , instead of just the method name.

Answer (score 0):

It is creating node with method name as you have define method called "OPTIMA_XR240_FAILED_MESSAGE_VALIDATION"

If you wants to get Customize name, You may pass it like:

```
 child = parentTest.get().createNode("Test node");
 childTest.set(child);
```

Everytime if you wants to give some numeric identification like "Test node 1", "Test node 2" and so on. You may get it by Count increment or loop and so it define like:

```
child = parentTest.get().createNode("Test node" +i);
childTest.set(child);
```

You can increment i value before method can get complete.

Comment: I agree with your comment , But in my case that particular test is doing a set of validations one by one (Say : 10 Validations) and the test data is provided from an excel sheet through data provider class. So if first validation is for 'Blank username validation' then the next will be 'Blank password validation'. So I have get a report which is meaningful with the validation it performs

Comment: I did't get you what exactly you want from question clarification and with reference to this comment.

Comment: What is that ? From where it throws.

Comment: Your requirement is not standard criteria for Report structure, Still if you want you can define node in @Test OPTIMA_XR240_FAILED_MESSAGE_VALIDATION method. child = parentTest.get().createNode(deviceTestData);

Comment: What is this **deviceTestData**. How can I generate that particular string dynamically from a test class ?

Comment: Its your second parameter from method. You need to pass String where you get this Text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pre-release snippet from extent-testng-plugin which will be released soon as part of version 4, but posting it here as this is how you will get the data-provider into your methods:

```
public class ExtentITestListener
    implements ITestListener {

    private static final ExtentReports EXTENT = Extent.getInstance();

    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> methodTest = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> dataProviderTest = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void onStart(ITestContext context) { }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        EXTENT.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {      
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        if (result.getParameters().length>0) {
            if (methodTest.get() != null && methodTest.get().getModel().getName().equals(methodName)) { } 
            else {
                createTest(result);
            }
            String paramName = Arrays.asList(result.getParameters()).toString();
            ExtentTest paramTest = methodTest.get().createNode(paramName);
            dataProviderTest.set(paramTest);
        } else {
            createTest(result);
        }
    }

    private void createTest(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        ExtentTest test = EXTENT.createTest(methodName);
        methodTest.set(test);

        String[] groups = result.getMethod().getGroups();
        if (groups.length > 0) {
            Arrays.asList(groups)
                .forEach(x -> methodTest.get().assignCategory(x));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        getTest(result).pass("Test passed");
    }

    private ExtentTest getTest(ITestResult result) {
        ExtentTest t = result.getParameters() != null && result.getParameters().length>0
                ? dataProviderTest.get()
                : methodTest.get();
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        getTest(result).fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        getTest(result).skip(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) { }

}


public class Extent 
    implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static class ExtentReportsLoader {

        private static final ExtentReports INSTANCE = new ExtentReports();

        static {
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ExtentReports getInstance() {
        return ExtentReportsLoader.INSTANCE;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ExtentReports readResolve() {
        return ExtentReportsLoader.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Since this is a ITestListener, you can add it directly to your test or base class like so:

```
@Listeners(ExtentITestListenerAdapter.class)
public class MyTests {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the above question which works fine for me. Put the below code inside your methods in listener class it can fetch the parameter from your test method

```
StringBuilder testName = new StringBuilder(result.getMethod().getMethodName());

Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();

if (parameters.length > 0) 
{

    StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) 
{
    //pass the parameter location which you want to add as a testname
        if(i == 4)
        {
              p.append(Utils.toString(parameters[i]));
        }                         
    }
}   
        
test = extent.createTest(testName.toString());
```